# Azure Devops Rest-api query with powershell

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I want to be able to create queries in an newly created query folder. But /i'm already stuck in the first action: create a new topfolder. It keeps throwing errors.
I'm not very experienced in powershell/rest-api's and the examples microsoft is providing are not very helpfull to novices.

I tried this and expected the creation of a new folder in the query folder structure:
I also tried using an absolute path in the form of
name ="/Shared Queries/Newfolder" and name="\Shared Queries\Newfolder", but the same error occurs.

```
    $pat = "aaa"
    $organization="bbb"
    $project = "ccc"
    $Response=""
    $uri = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/wit/queries/{query}?api-version=7.1-preview.2"
    $body = @{
            name     = "Newfolder"
            isFolder = "true"
    }
    $jsonbody = ConvertTo-Json $body
    $headers = @{
        Authorization = "Basic {0}" -f [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($pat)"))
        "Content-Type"  = "application/json-patch+json"
    }
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $jsonbody
```

-RESULT-

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"TF400898: An Internal Error Occurred. Activity Id: c110a6ff
-5b88-4868-a614-3c7cad2423b7.","typeName":"System.Web.Http.HttpResponseException, System.Web.Http","typeKey":"HttpResponseE
xception","errorCode":0,"eventId":0}
At C:\Users\harry\qry-topfolder.ps1:20 char:13
+ $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -Headers $header ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebExcepti 
   on
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `{query}` with the target folder path in `$uri`. Example:

```
$user = ""
$token = "<pat>" #https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page
$teamProject = "team_project_name"
$orgUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/<org>"
$targetQueryFolder = "Shared Queries" #should exist

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

$queriesUrl = "$orgUrl/$teamProject/_apis/wit/queries/$($targetQueryFolder)?api-version=5.0"

$body = "{`"name`": `"Newfolder`", `"isFolder`": `"true`"}"

function InvokePostRequest ($PostUrl, $body)
{   
    return Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $PostUrl -Method Post -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}  -Body $body
}

InvokePostRequest $queriesUrl $body
```

Additionally your `$body` is not in JSON format. Use `ConvertTo-Json` or just make it like in my example.

Comment: Thank for your solution. That saves me a lot of headaches!
In reaction on your json-formatting of  $body. I thought I would achieve that with the statement:
$jsonbody = ConvertTo-Json $body

Comment: I also noticed that you use ?api-version=5.0 in your script, where I used?api-version=7.1-preview.2. 
Is there a guideline for this? How do I know which one to use?

Comment: @user23314406 `version=5.0` from my old scripts. You may use newer API without any worries.  To check if some function exists in api, you may switch versions on the left corner: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2